# Edge weights with the lemon graph library

Tags: c++, graph, lemon-graph-library

I am using the [Lemon](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/) graph library.

I want to assign integer weights to the edges. Thus I am using [EdgeMap](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.3/a00144.html). Unfortunality my code doesn't compile.

```
no matching function for call to 'lemon::concepts::Graph::EdgeMap<int>::EdgeMap(lemon::ListGraph&)'
```

Any ideas?

```
#include <lemon/list_graph.h>
#include <lemon/concepts/graph.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace lemon;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{    

   ListGraph g;
   lemon::concepts::Graph::EdgeMap<int> map(g);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to call a forbidden copy constructor here. 
The copy constructor of [`lemon::ListGraph()`](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.3/a00237.html#a62812b9a8c8bedabc1aeec208cf20d46) is marked as `private` and `EdgeMap (const Graph &)` wants a [`const Graph &`](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.3/a00144.html) parameter.

In other words, the concepts for `ListGraph` and `EdgeMap` don't match. As far as I understood from their documentation `ListGraph` provides the [`concepts::Digraph`](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.3/a00235.html) concept, where `EdgeMap` requires a [`ReferenceMap`](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.3/a00321.html) compliant implementation.